# Table Row Height Will Not Change

Tags: html, css, razor

I have the following CSS:

```
<style>
    .tableLine tr {
        border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
        max-height: 10px !important;
        height: 10px !important;
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
</style>
```

And the following code:

```
                                  <table id="list" class="tableLine">
                                    <thead style="position:sticky;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><b>Created By<br /> Created Date</b></th>
                                            <th><b>Changed By <br /> Changed Date</b></th>
                                            <th><b>Remark</b></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.remark.remarkList.Count(); i++)
                                        {
                                            <tr style="height:10px;max-height:10px;margin-bottom:0px">
                                                <td style="min-width:100px;">@Model.remark.remarkList[i].created_by <br /> @Model.remark.remarkList[i].create_date</td>
                                                <td style="min-width:100px;">@Model.remark.remarkList[i].changed_by <br /> @Model.remark.remarkList[i].change_date</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Model.remark.remarkList[i].remark
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                       }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

And the row height refuses to stay at 10px. I expands to accommodate the size of @Model.remark.remarkList[i].remark everytime.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below adding the default tag in front of your class. Please share your input in regards to the results afterwards.

```
    table.tableLine tr {
    border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    max-height: 10px !important;
    height: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Used the class above and still did not alter the row height. I know the class is working because the border shows, the row height just refuses to change.

Comment: Oh never mind, typo on my end, it did work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that, we are honored to be of assistance. Happy coding, @J.Cart.